# Celery Task ECS Termination Issue - Need Help Updating Decorator for Handling ProtectionEnabled State Changes

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-ecs

**Explanation:**

I have a Django application where I am running multiple Celery tasks on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS), using SQS as the broker. I am encountering an issue where the Celery tasks are being started in an existing ECS task once the previous one is completed. The issue arises because my decorator changes the status of ProtectionEnabled from true to false, and after a couple of seconds, the ECS task is terminated. The newly started task then fails to work. Below is the command I am running to start celery task.

```
celery -A myapp_settings.celery worker --concurrency=1 l info -Q sqs-celery
```

I am using alerts on CloudWatch to check messages in broker and terminate those ECS tasks that are completed. The problem is that celery is starting task in existing ECS task once the previous one was completed. It would not be a problem but my decorator changes the status of ProtectionEnabled from true to false and after 20 seconds ECS task is terminated and newly started task is not working anymore.

**Question:**

I am considering updating my decorator to change back the ProtectionEnabled value from false to true if a new Celery task starts, but I am unsure how to implement this.

**Code:**

container_decorator.py

```
class ContainerAgent:
    class Error(Exception):
        pass

    class RequestError(Error, IOError):
        pass

    def __init__(
        self,
        ecs_agent_uri: str,
        timeout: int = 10,
        session: requests.Session = None,
        logger: logging.Logger = None,
    ) -> None:
        self._ecs_agent_uri = ecs_agent_uri
        self._timeout = timeout

        self._session = session or requests.Session()
        self._logger = logger or logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def _request(self, *, path: str, data: Optional[dict] = None) -> dict:
        url = f"{self._ecs_agent_uri}{path}"
        self._logger.info(f"Performing request... {url=} {data=}")

        try:
            response = self._session.put(url=url, json=data, timeout=self._timeout)
            self._logger.info(f"Got response. {response.status_code=} {response.content=}")

            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            response_body = e.response.text if e.response is not None else None
            self._logger.warning(f"Request error! {url=} {data=} {e=} {response_body=}")

            raise self.RequestError(str(e)) from e

    def toggle_scale_in_protection(self, *, enable: bool = True, expire_in_minutes: int = 2880):
        response = self._request(
            path="/task-protection/v1/state",
            data={"ProtectionEnabled": enable, "ExpiresInMinutes": expire_in_minutes},
        )

        try:
            return response["protection"]["ProtectionEnabled"]
        except KeyError as e:
            raise self.Error(f"Task scale-in protection endpoint error: {response=}") from e


def enable_scale_in_protection(*, logger: logging.Logger = None):
    def decorator(f):
        if not (ecs_agent_uri := os.getenv("ECS_AGENT_URI")):
            (logger or logging).warning(f"Scale-in protection not enabled. {ecs_agent_uri=}")
            return f

        client = ContainerAgent(ecs_agent_uri=ecs_agent_uri, logger=logger)

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                client.toggle_scale_in_protection(enable=True)
            except client.Error as e:
                (logger or logging).warning(f"Scale-in protection not enabled. {e}")
                protection_set = False
            else:
                protection_set = True

            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                if protection_set:
                    client.toggle_scale_in_protection(enable=False)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

celery_tasks.py

```
@shared_task(name="add_spider_schedule", base=AbortableTask)
@enable_scale_in_protection(logger=get_task_logger(__name__))
def add_spider_schedule(user_id, spider_id):
    settings_module = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')
    if settings_module == 'myapp_settings.settings.production':
        return add_spider_schedule_production(user_id, spider_id, add_spider_schedule)
    else:
        return print('Unknown settings module')

def add_spider_schedule_production(user_id, spider_id, task_object):
    """
    Adds the schedule for the specified spider.
    :param spider_id: The ID of the spider to schedule.
    :return: A string representation of the spider and task IDs.
    """
    # below is the logging setup to include all 'prints' (both in the below & in the spider script) in the logger
    logger = get_task_logger(task_object.request.id)
    old_outs = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    rlevel = add_spider_schedule.app.conf.worker_redirect_stdouts_level
    add_spider_schedule.app.log.redirect_stdouts_to_logger(logger, rlevel)

    # Get the Spider model instance
    spider = Spider.objects.get(id=spider_id)

    # Get the current user
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    # Get the names of the relevant files from the model instance
    spider_config_file = spider.spider_config_file.file
    yaml_config_file = spider.yaml_config_file.file
    template_file = spider.template_file.file
    mongodb_database_name = spider.mongodb_collection.database_name
    mongodb_collection_name = spider.mongodb_collection.collection_name

    # Read the contents of the files from the S3 bucket
    spider_config_file_contents = load_content_from_s3(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, rf"{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/{spider_config_file}")
    yaml_config_path = load_content_from_s3(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, rf"{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/{yaml_config_file}")
    input_file_path = load_content_from_s3(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, rf"{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/{template_file}")

    # Convert the JSON-encoded keyword arguments to a dictionary
    kwargs = json.loads(spider.kwargs) if spider.kwargs else {}

    # Create a module from the contents of the spider_config_file
    spider_module = import_module(spider_config_file_contents, "spider_config")
 
    is_scraping_finished = False

    async def run_spider():
        try:
            await spider_module.run(
                yaml_config_path=yaml_config_path,
                # page_type = page_type,
                # fields_to_scrape = fields_to_scrape,
                input_file_path=input_file_path,
                mongodb_name=mongodb_database_name,
                mongodb_collection_name=mongodb_collection_name,
                task_object=task_object,
                mode="sf-lab",
                **kwargs
            )
            nonlocal is_scraping_finished
            # print(f"CELERY TASK OBJECT DETAILS: {task_object.request}")
            is_scraping_finished = True
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"An error occurred while running the spider: {e}")

    async def check_if_aborted():
        while True:
            if task_object.is_aborted():
                print("Parralel function detected that task was cancelled.")
                raise Exception("task was cancelled")
            elif is_scraping_finished:
                # print("Scraping finished - breaking check-if-aborted loop")
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(run_spider(), check_if_aborted()))

    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = old_outs  # needed for logging part

    return f"[spider: {spider_id}, task_id: {task_object.request.id}]"
```